# mod_rewrite not loading css and js files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a weird problem with a mod_rewrite condition / rule.

This is the condition and rule I'm using.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My problem is if I visit www.example.com and www.example.com/page it loads fine but when I try to load www.example.com/page/category it loads the page but cannot find the css and javascript. It tries to load them from page/css instead of the / directory.

Any thoughts on what I've done wrong? I had a search on here and tried a few things like add

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|mp3|wav|txt)$
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(images|css|javascript)(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But that didn't seem to make much difference.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a silent rewrite will not tell the visitor's web browser that they are in fact looking at a page from a different directory path.

So a request for /page leaves the browser (correctly) thinking that it is looking at a resource which is in the top-level public directory on the web server, as are the images and CSS files.

But a request for /page/category leaves the browser (wrongly) thinking that it is looking at a resource which is in a sub-directory called page. So when the browser sends requests for the CSS and image files, it will ask the server to look for them in the /page/ sub-directory, which does not really exist. So the server returns 404 codes when the browser tries to fetch image and CSS files.

One way to get around this is to change the paths to CSS, image and other page-referenced resources to absolute paths. Start them with a forward-slash so that they are anchored relative to the actual top-level public directory. This is probably the best way to proceed if you only have a small number of resource paths to update. For example, change:

```
src="image-name.png"
```

into

```
src="/image-name.png"
```

This will force the browser to request the file using an absolute path rather than deduce the wrong location based on a relative path.

To remove the need for a RewriteCond, you can change your RewriteRule to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+(?:/[a-z]+)*)$ index.php?params=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will not match anything which contains a period (dot) symbol, so requests for image and CSS files will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just using the [`base` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#the-base-element), and removing the "/" before the images?