# Move top level domain to sub-directory to host multiple sites on same domain using Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have multiple sites on different domains using a SaaS LAMP application.  I'm attempting to move all of the sites under a single domain, and allow for additional sites to be added without monkeying around with Apache configs.

For example...

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
```

will get moved to

```
www.domain.com/domain1
www.domain.com/domain2
```

Static file will still appear in the html as having a top level src attribute

```
/some-image.jpg
```

But really the file is now located in

```
document_root/domain1/some-image.jpg
```

So I have to add in the "domain1" section to the path for static files.What would be the best way of handling this in an apache config?  Or is there another easier method for accomplishing what I want to do?

Comment: Bear in mind that a rewrite is likely to break references to image files and other on-page resources which use a relative file path. For explanation, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611084/mod-rewrite-not-loading-css-and-js-files/15603872#15603872

Answer (score 0):

Use the Linux command `sed`:

```
cd www.domain.com/domain1/
sed -i 's/document_root/document_root\/domain1/g' *
```

This will change all occurrences of `document_root` to `document_root/domain1` for all instances within `www.domain.com/domain1/`.