# .htaccess mod_rewrite based on domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule in my htaccess, I need to modify it to add variable to the end of the re-written url. Basically I have two domains pointing to the same hosting, and I am showing different sites  depending on which domain it used.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?rrr\.me 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rrr
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /rrr/$1 [L]
```

If someone goes to `rrr.me` or `www.rrr.me` they get the index.php in the rrr directory of my website. This works great!

I now need to be able to add a variable to the index.php. So someone will type in `rrr.me/abc` and it will append the abc to the end of the index.php in this fashion `index.php?var1=abc`

NEW REWRITE RULES AFTER ADVICE FROM Olaf Dietsche IN COMMENTS.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?rrr\.me 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rrr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/
Rewriterule ^.*$ /rrr/index.php?rrr=$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?rrr\.me
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rrr
Rewriterule ^assets/.*$ /rrr/$0 [L]
```

Comment: I modified the final rules. The `!assets` condition must be added to the *first* rule and the second rule must have the `!rrr` rule as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks for all the help, really appreciate it. Also I have learnt quite a bit :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append the requested URL as a query string

```
Rewriterule ^.*$ /rrr/index.php?var1=$0 [L]
```

To exclude the `assets` directory, you must use an additional [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?rrr\.me
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rrr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /rrr/$1 [L]
```

For the assets files, you can use a similar redirect

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?rrr\.me
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rrr
Rewriterule ^assets/.*$ /rrr/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I replaced the third line of my rule with your line, and now I receive an internal server error. Any ideas?

Comment: @superphonic Which URL have you requested? Do you have access to the server logs?

Comment: After adding your Rewriterule, I went to rrr.me and get an internal server error. When I put my Rewriterule rule back it works as expected. I have not changed the RewriteCond.

Comment: @superphonic I changed the regular expression to include the root dir. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Oooo very close. The variable is passed to index.php OK now. However now my images, js files and css files are no longer found. They are located in a folder called "assets" within the /rrr directory. assets is being picked up as the variable and appended to the index.php file it looks like. Sorry, probably should have told you there was a sub directory in that directory.

Comment: @superphonic See my answer to another question to understand why this is happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611084/mod-rewrite-not-loading-css-and-js-files/15603872#15603872

Comment: I am still not having any luck. I have updated my question with my current code. It is adding whatever is after the / to index.php variable, including the assets folder. For example if I go to 'rrr.me/assets/css/style.css' the 'var1' variable is populated with `assests/css/style.css' Also if I do not put anything after the / the `var1` variable is populated with 'index.php'?